# Designing a twenty questions algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, puzzle

I am interested in writing a [twenty questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Questions) algorithm similar to what [akinator](http://en.akinator.com/#) and, to a lesser extent, [20q.net](http://www.20q.net) uses. The latter seems to focus more on objects, explicitly telling you not to think of persons or places. One could say that akinator is more general, allowing you to think of literally anything, including abstractions such as "my brother".

The problem with this is that I don't know what algorithm these sites use, but from what I read they seem to be using a probabilistic approach in which questions are given a certain fitness based on how many times they have lead to correct guesses. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887533/how-do-20-questions-ai-algorithms-work) presents several techniques, but rather vaguely, and I would be interested in more details.

So, what could be an accurate and efficient algorithm for playing twenty questions?

I am interested in details regarding:

1. What question to ask next.
2. How to make the best guess at the end of the 20 questions.
3. How to insert a new object and a new question into the database.
4. How to query (1, 2) and update (3) the database efficiently.

I realize this may not be easy and I'm not asking for code or a 2000 words presentation. Just a few sentences about each operation and the underlying data structures should be enough to get me started.

Comment: im sure cstheory.stackexchange.com might be better...

Comment: @Daniel A. White - I've thought about it, but based on previous discussion this seems to involve only trivial data structures. I'm just sketchy on the details, but my intuition tells me they're not research-level-difficult. If I'm not mistaken, 20q.net started as a class project. Perhaps I'll try there too, but I'd like to leave this one up for now as well.

Comment: This kind of question would probably be closed on CSTheory. There was a similar question on stats.stackexchange, and I posted an outline of neural network based approach -- http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/akinator-com-and-naive-bayes-classifier/6262#6262

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update, 10+ years later**

I'm now hosting a (WIP, but functional) implementation here: https://twentyq.evobyte.org/ with the code here: https://github.com/evobyte-apps/open-20-questions. It's based on the same rough idea listed below.

---

Well, over three years later, I did it (although I didn't work full time on it). I hosted a crude implementation at http://twentyquestions.azurewebsites.net/ if anyone is interested (please don't teach it too much wrong stuff yet!).

It wasn't that hard, but I would say it's the non-intuitive kind of not hard that you don't immediately think of. My methods include some trivial fitness-based ranking, ideas from [reinforcement learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) and a [round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) method of scheduling new questions to be asked. All of this is implemented on a normalized relational database.

My basic ideas follow. If anyone is interested, I will share code as well, just contact me. I plan on making it open source eventually, but once I have done a bit more testing and reworking. So, my ideas:

- an **Entities** table that holds the characters and objects played;
- a **Questions** table that holds the questions, which are also submitted by users;
- an **EntityQuestions** table holds entity-question relations. This holds the number of times each answer was given for each question in relation to each entity (well, those for which the question was asked for anyway). It also has a Fitness field, used for ranking questions from "more general" down to "more specific";
- a **GameEntities** table is used for ranking the entities according to the answers given so far for each on-going game. An answer of `A` to a question `Q` pushes up all the entities for which the majority answer to question `Q` is `A`;
- The first question asked is picked from those with the highest sum of fitnesses across the **EntityQuestions** table;
- Each next question is picked from those with the highest fitness associated with the currently top entries in the `GameEntities` table. Questions for which the expected answer is Yes are favored even before the fitness, because these have more chances of consolidating the current top ranked entity;
- If the system is quite sure of the answer even before all 20 questions have been asked, it will start asking questions not associated with its answer, so as to learn more about that entity. This is done in a round-robin fashion from the global questions pool right now. **Discussion:** is round-robin fine, or should it be fully random?
- Premature answers are also given under certain conditions and probabilities;
- Guesses are given based on the rankings in **GameEntities**. This allows the system to account for lies as well, because it never eliminates any possibility, just decreases its likeliness of being the answer;
- After each game, the fitness and answers statistics are updated accordingly: fitness values for entity-question associations decrease if the game was lost, and increase otherwise.

I can provide more details if anyone is interested. I am also open to collaborating on improving the algorithms and implementation.

Comment: yeah... if you can share the code, it could be very cool.... I'm very corious!! thank you

Comment: Hi @IVlad is it possible to share the source code with me ? Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I'm really curious about the code now. Would you mind sharing it with me?

Comment: Upvoted because it's great that you put out the source code and came back to update the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I am trying try to write a python implementation using a naïve Bayesian network for learning and minimizing the expected entropy after the question has been answered as criterium for selecting a question (with an epsilon chance of selecting a random question in order to learn more about that question), following the ideas in http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-tol/2010-March/000912.html. I have put what I got so far on [github](http://github.com/Anaphory/open20q).

1. Preferably choose questions with low remaining entropy expectation. (For putting together something quickly, I stole from ε-greedy multi-armed bandit learning and use: With probability 1–ε: Ask the question with the lowest remaining entropy expectation. With probability ε: Ask any random question. However, this approach seems far from optimal.)
2. Since my approach is a Bayesian network, I obtain the probabilities of the objects and can ask for the most probable object.

   - A new object is added as new column to the probabilities matrix, with low a priori probability and the answers to the questions as given if given or as guessed by the Bayes network if not given. (I expect that this second part would work much better if I would add Bayes network structure learning instead of just using naive Bayes.)
   - Similarly, a new question is a new row in the matrix. If it comes from user input, probably only very few answer probabilities are known, the rest needs to be guessed. (In general, if you can get objects by asking for properties, you can obtain properties by asking if given objects have them or not, and the transformation between these is essentially Bayes' theorem and breaks down to transposition in the easiest case. The guessing quality should improve again once the network has an appropriate structure.)
3. (This is a problem, since I calculate lots of probabilities. My goal is to do it using database-oriented sparse tensor calculations optimized for working with weighted directed acyclic graphs.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very interesting question. Unfortunately I don't have a full answer, let me just write down the ideas I could come up with in 10 minutes:

- If you are able to halve the set of available answers on each question, you can distinguish between 2^20 ~ 1 million "objects". Your set is probably going to be larger, so it's right to assume that sometimes you *have to make a guess*.
- You want to maximize *utility*. Some objects are chosen more often than others. If you want to make good guesses you have to take into consideration the *weight* of each object (= the probability of that object being picked) when creating the tree.
- If you trust a little bit of your users you can gain knowledge based on their answers. This also means that you cannot use a *static* tree to ask questions because then you'll get the answers for the same questions.. and you'll learn nothing new if you encounter with the same object.
- If a simple question is not able to divide the set to two halves, you could combine them to get better results: eg: "is the object green *or* blue?". "green *or* has a round shape?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! First of all, I don't think my set is going to be larger than 1 million, I think it's actually going to be a lot less. How many objects / people do you think you could come up with if given, say, a week? There will always be people who can come up with more, but how much more? A lot of what smarter people are able to think of will overlap with what you thought of, and most people play popular choices anyway. I think even 100 000 entries for the objects table is an overstatement.

Comment: Second, your first "if" is a very big if. I think it's rarely possible to halve the set of available answers. You can probably do it early on with questions like "is your character male?", "is your character real?" etc., but as questions get more specific, you end up eliminating either a lot more or a lot less than half. This reduces from the advantage of what I said before, but not by a lot I think: even if this question doesn't cut the number of possibilities by a lot, the answer to it should usually help the next question to do so.

Comment: I've actually given this more thought over the past year and I came up with an apparently decent (in my opinion) theoretical model that would be relatively easy to implement. I didn't have the time to implement it yet however. It uses what you say in your last 2 points. If you have time to look over it and maybe discuss it, drop me an email please (email in profile).

Comment: Yeah I know that's a big if.. especially in the early training period when you try learn which questions help to make better decisions. I only wrote that as a theoretical limit. But I think you should be able to get pretty close to it (2^18 or 2^19), see my update.

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to see how good a decision tree based algorithm would serve you. The trick here is purely in the learning/sorting of the tree. I'd like to note that this is stuff I remember from AI class and student work in the AI working group and should be taken with a semi-large grain (or nugget) of salt.

To answer the questions:

1. You just walk the tree :)
2. This is a big downside of decision trees. You'd only have one guess that can be attached to the end nodes of the tree at depth 20 (or earlier, if the tree is still sparse).
3. There are whole books dedicated to this topic. As far as I remember from AI class you try minimize entropy at all times, so you want to ask questions that ideally divide the set of remaining objects into two sets of equal size. I'm afraid you'd have to look this up in AI books.
4. Decision trees are highly efficient during the query phase, as you literally walk the tree and follow the 'yes' or 'no' branch at each node. Update efficiency depends on the learning algorithm applied. You might be able to do this offline as in a nightly batched update or something like that.

Comment: Decisions trees are also problematic when allowing multiple answers. For example, what do you do when someone answers "I don't know"? 19 correct answers and one "I don't know" answer should still allow you to guess right.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a problem. Each node could have three (or more) branches like "Yes", "No" and "I don't know". It doesn't really change any of the fundamental approaches or algorithms. In fact more branches mean less collisions and help mitigate the problem in question 2.

Comment: But "I don't know" should keep both the "Yes" and "No" branches viable, so the tree would have to be augmented for this purpose. A similar problem is when a **wrong** answer is given. A wrong answer, at any step, would definitely mean you will get the wrong guess in the end, in the case of a classic decision tree. It might be possible (and maybe even recommended) to use decision trees, but I think they need to be enhanced a bit to get a decent algorithm. If you mean building a whole new entry for each "I don't know" answer, leading to the same guess, wouldn't this use a lot of memory?

Comment: You'd likely have to roll your own decision tree implementation. Nearly all I've seen work as classifiers on a complete set of features. They don't easily allow you to "walk" the tree, although this is certainly possible.

Comment: I implemented a basic 20Q algorithm. I'd recommend having at least these two default choices for each question. 1) "I don't know", meaning there's a valid answer to the question, but it's unknown, and 2) "Irrelevant", meaning there's no valid answer to the question.