# What kind of algorithm is behind the Akinator game?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

It always amazed me how the [Akinator app](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/akinator-the-genie/id484090401?mt=8) could guess a character by asking just several questions. So I wonder what kind of algorithm or method let it do that? Is there a name for that class of algorithms and where can I read more about them?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, there is a name for these class of algorithms - it is called **[classification algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification)** in the field of [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). [Decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) is one example for classification algorithm.

In this classification problem, the features for the algorithm are the answers to the question.

Deciding which question should be asked next can be done in various ways - for example by trying to maximize the predicted (or mean) [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy) from the next question.

Comment: I will add to amit's reply that it shouldn't surprise you that few questions are able to find the character. The screenshot I saw had 5 answer possibilities. By asking just 8 questions, you can distinguish between 8^5 = 2^15 = 32768 characters, which is enough to cover the characters thought up by the vast majority of people.

Comment: @HerrKaputt - Theoretically yes, but remember that there is "noise" - people might mistake or give different significance (strongly agree/weakly agree) to the same question. (This is why plain binary search fails in these cases and you need something that is more based on statistics, which is exactly what classification algorithms are aiming to do)

Comment: @HerrKaputt the number of permutations should be `5^8` not `8^5`, however, there are only two options not five. "Don't know" is to ignore a question and the "probably" variants are only to make the "yes" and "no" answers weaker. So the number of permutations for 8 questions is only `2^8` which is `256`.

Comment: @dualed: We are getting way off topic - but there is no reason to ignore "I don't know" or to use "probably" same as "yes". For example, think of the question "Did your character ever modeled" - A "I don't know" answer will help the agent identify you are probably not talking about [Bar Refaeli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Refaeli).

Comment: @amit I know there is a reason, but in the analysis section when you complete a "game" you can see that Akinator does in fact ignore "don't know" answers and that it only has "Yes" and "No" answers stored.

Comment: Oops, you are right, it's 5^8. My bad. Too bad I can't edit the comment.

Comment: I would not say that these are classification algorithms (although they are doing that). These kind of algorithms (or systems) are called Expert Systems.

Answer (score 7):

- Algorythm of Akinator is NOT Decision trees, because Decision trees have no mistakes-indulgence + no intelligent system of next question choose
- Also it is NOT based on Neural Network. As akinator exist from 2007-08-31 when neural networks wasn't used a lot

---

Main characteristics of algorithm:

- Self-educating
- Mistakes-indulgence
- Intelligent system of next question choose

Akinator game algorithm algorythm is called "[Fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) expert system" or "Expert system based on [Fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic)".

I had wrote one some time ago on C#, you can find it by link: https://github.com/ukushu/AkinatorEngine

---

additional info you can read on wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Экспертная_система](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Answer (score 6):

This game is sometimes known as *20 Questions*. There are some questions on SO on it, e.g.:

- [How do 20 questions AI algorithms work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887533/how-do-20-questions-ai-algorithms-work)
- [Designing a twenty questions algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915799/designing-a-twenty-questions-algorithm?lq=1)
- [the akinator is running with a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11031143/108915)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what exactly algorithm Akinator uses, but here I have put open-source an algorithm that achieves the same effect: https://github.com/srogatch/ProbQA

Basically we use a cube of `N(Questions)` times `N(Answer Options)` times `N(Targets)` , see https://github.com/srogatch/ProbQA/blob/master/ProbQA/PqaCore/CpuEngine.decl.h .

We train the cube by applying Bayesian formula with independence assumption, see https://github.com/srogatch/ProbQA/blob/master/ProbQA/PqaCore/CEEvalQsSubtaskConsider.cpp

Because the code is highly optimized for AVX2 and multi-threading, it may be hard to read. It may be easier to read the CUDA code for the same: https://github.com/srogatch/ProbQA/blob/master/ProbQA/PqaCore/CudaEngineGpu.cu

An application of this algorithm is also available as a [website to recommend a game](http://probqa.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is like an expert system, with B-Tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

i have a small project to build a dynamic quiz for 'find your taste' and i want to share it with you :

---

```js
const quizData =
{
  "title": "Quiz about Foo", "questions": [

    { "text": "Tea or Coffee ?", "answers": [["Coffee","coffee"], ["Tea","tea"]] },
    { "text": "What type of coffee do you like ?", "parentanswer": "coffee", "answers": [["Arabic","arabic_coffee"], ["Turkish","turkish-coffee"], ["Espresso","espresso-coffee"], ["Black","black-coffee"]] },
       { "text": "What type of tea do you like ?", "parentanswer": "tea", "answers": [["Green","green-tea"], ["Red","red-tea"], ["Earl","earl-tea"]] },
       { "text": "Do you like it stronge ?", "parentanswer": "black-coffee", "answers": [["Yes","stronge-coffee"], ["No","notstronge-coffee"]] },
       { "text": "Do you like it light ?", "parentanswer": "stronge-coffee", "answers": [["Yes","light-coffee"], ["No","notlight-coffee"]] },
  ],
  "products":[
  { "name": "Japanese Green Tea" , "characteristic": "tea,green-tea"},
  {"name":"Organic Sencha Green Tea" , "characteristic": "tea,green-tea"},
  {"name":"Yogi Tea" , "characteristic": "tea,green-tea"},

  {"name":"South African Rooibos" , "characteristic": "tea,red-tea"},
  {"name":"Lipton" , "characteristic": "tea,red-tea"}, 

  {"name":"Alrifai" , "characteristic": "coffee,arabic-coffee"},
  {"name":"Baja"  , "characteristic": "coffee,arabic-coffee"},

  {"name":"Tim Hortons"  , "characteristic": "coffee,black-coffee,stronge-coffee"},
  {"name":"Starbucks"  , "characteristic": "coffee,black-coffee,light-coffee"},
  {"name":"Espresso Craft Blend"  , "characteristic": "coffee,  espresso-coffee"},

  {"name":"Baja"  , "characteristic": "coffee,  turkish-coffee"},
  
  ]
};

Vue.component('question', {
  template: `
<div v-if="question" class=" m-2" >
    <h3 class="text-primary">Find your taste</h3> <br/> 

  <h4>Question {{ questionNumber }} :</h4><br/>
  <h3 class="text-primary">{{ question.text }} </h3> <br/> 
 
    <div @change="submitAnswer" class=" btn-group-toggle"  >
    
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary m-2" v-for="(mcanswer,index) in question.answers" >
     <input :value="mcanswer" type="radio" name="currentQuestion" :id="'answer'+index" v-model="answer"  > {{mcanswer[0]}}
    </label> 
  
    </div>  
  
</div>
`,
  data() {
    return {
      answer: ''
    }
  },
  props: ['question', 'question-number'],
  methods: {
    submitAnswer: function (e) {
      app.handleAnswer(this);
    }
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#quiz',
  data() {
    return {
      resultsStage: false,
      title: '',
      questions: [],
      products:[],
      currentQuestion: 0,
      answers: [],
      correct: 0,
      result: '',
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.title = quizData.title;
    this.questions = quizData.questions;
    this.products = quizData.products;
  },
  methods: {
    handleAnswer(e) { 
      this.answers[this.currentQuestion] = e.answer[0];
     
      var i ;
      for(i=0; this.currentQuestion < this.questions.length; i++)
      { 
        //find child question for selected answer
        if(typeof(this.questions[i].parentanswer)!='undefined')
        {
          if(e.answer[1] === this.questions[i].parentanswer)
          {
            this.result +=  e.answer[1] + ',';
            this.currentQuestion=i;
            this.counter++;
            break;
          }
        }
        //no child for this question => end of quiz
        if(i+1 == this.questions.length)
        {
          this.result +=  e.answer[1];
          this.handleResults();
          this.resultsStage = true;
          break;
        }
      } 


    },
    handleResults() {
     // window.location.href = "http://hadict.com"+this.result + "/?sl=ar";
      var i ;
 var hasResult=false;
 for(i=0; i < this.products.length; i++)
 { 
   if( this.products[i].characteristic==this.result)
   {   
    this.result = this.products[i].name; 
    hasResult=true;
    break;
   } 
   
 }
 if(!hasResult)
 {
  this.result="no result";  
 }
   
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="quiz">
    <div v-if="!resultsStage">
      <question :question="questions[currentQuestion]" :question-number="counter+1"></question>
    </div>

    <div v-if="resultsStage">
      <div
        style="justify-content: space-between;display: flex;flex-direction: column;align-items: center;margin: 10px;">
        <h3 class="text-primary">Done</h3>
        <h3 class="text-primary">Your best drink is : </h3>  
        <h3 class="text-primary">{{result}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve Akinator's effect by Bayes theorem. I found this really interesting article about it: [Building Akinator with Python using Bayes Theorem](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-akinator-with-python-using-bayes-theorem-216253c98daa).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34649480)

Answer (score -1):

Akinator uses more of binary trees. So, the root node is the first question. This goes on inner and inner. Probably, Akinator also gets the location where you are and links the questions. I have developed my own Akinator named as Ankusha. I have used a pattern matching algorithm. It's quite complicated to say the way Ankusha works. You can get the source code from this github link.
[Ankusha-The Mind Reader](https://github.com/AnuragSimha/Ankusha-TheMindReader)
Ankusha finishes the guess within five questions. He confirms the movie he guessed with you. If you click on 'No', next five questions are asked. This iteration continues up to twenty one questions. It is a Python 3.7 program, which requires the PIL and pygame module to be installed compulsorily. Please do try it out.

**NOTE: Make sure that you read the file README.md before proceeding with the installation of the app. All licences are done under the GNU GPLv3 (GNU General Public Licence version 3.0).**

Comment: "Ankusha finishes the guess within five questions."

5 questions for 9 movies in the "database"?