# Python and Mysql tuple search

Tags: python, mysql

Hello good afternoon!!! 
I am new to Python programming, and recently got a job at college to implement a similar program to akinator, using the desired language, for easier, I decided to use Python. The idea is to ask the user questions, and return only one value based on the answers obtained. I did this in a mysql test bank, static, with "lead" questions in the code, and a select at the end using all the parameters. However, this method will be very laborious to create the bank and for the user to answer, because it would have to answer 50 questions for the result to be unique. I thought then of making a table of questions and one of results. My idea is to present random questions and use an id in the question to select. Example: - Is the car Fiat brand? According to the answer, I would like to select, storing the results that satisfy the condition, and after that ask a new question by applying new select only on these already filtered values. With this I believe that the number of questions would be smaller, and they could be asked at random (one of the teacher's requirements). However, I have no idea how to apply this in practice, ie how to store the results somewhere, and reselect only those stored values. This loop would be made until the result is = 1. Could you help me? Follow what you have done so far.

```
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'python')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    version = cur.fetchone()
    print("Database version: {}".format(version[0]))

print("Hello I am the diviner!!!")
print("Think of something and I will guess !!!")
print("Answer the questions using 's' for YES and 'n' for NO followed by ENTER !!!")
comecar = input("We can start?\n")
if comecar == "S":
    print("There goes the first question")
else:
    print("Try again")
vmarca = input("The car and brand FIAT?\n")
vportas = input("The car has 2 doors?\n")
vpotencia = input("The car is 1.0?\n")
vtipo = input("Is the car utility?\n")
vtipo2 = input("Is the car hatch?\n")
qry_p = ("SELECT nome  FROM resultados where fiat = '"+vmarca+"'AND 2portas='"+vportas+"'AND pot='"+vpotencia+"'AND utilitario='"+vtipo+"'AND hatch='"+vtipo2+"'")
cur.execute(qry_p)
result = cur.fetchone()
print("The car you thought is", result)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649646/what-kind-of-algorithm-is-behind-the-akinator-game

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks for now.