# I want to make a website that gives an output depends on your selections

Tags: html, css, sql

I want to make a website that gives an output text depends on your a few multiple choice question answers.

For example; You chose your symptoms from a few questions and at the end of the form it gives you the true medicine

Where should i start, how do i use a medicine list? sql datebase? What i need to do to create a website like this?

I know how to use a sql db and css.

Comment: You don't need an SQL database to do this. I have done it before with just jquery. You record what HTML elements like divs are clicked on and you hide and show elements based on that. Or you can use Limesurvey https://www.limesurvey.org/en

Comment: Stavk Overflow has a policy of not allowing programming questions where the person has not made an effort to solve the problem himself

Comment: Learn jquery http://jquery.com

Comment: They moved the open source Limesurvey to a different website https://community.limesurvey.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, i think u should / have to create a website like related to health and all. So i'll suggest u to go with frontend with HTML,CSS,BOOTSTRAP etc + backend with JS & PHP and for Databse go with MySQL.As u mentioned in ur qus, so u can put some QNA between user and a machine or else multiple radio buttons or checkboxes. U can take data as API and do all stuff in backend like fetching data and giving related medicines or output at the end of the form or create ur own json file and in that all data should be there related to every medicines. So this is what u can do all this & in advance u can also go with pyhton if u know it will be best for that about fetching the data and giving the output. well choose the best and do the best , and Best of luck for ur Website!

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer for me. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a small project, for the data, I'd use a simple database with each medicine having a bunch of symptoms next to it (m:n relation). Then display percentage match of a few for each based on count of symptoms clicked.

The clicking itself sounds like JavaScript (or jQuery). Display buttons, save which symptoms are clicked, then bring in the items with most matches.

If you wanted something more complex, for a larger project, take a look at the [algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649646/what-kind-of-algorithm-is-behind-the-akinator-game) behind Akinator or similar apps. Machine learning could be very useful when it comes to medicine, but I'm not well versed on that topic.