# data structure for storing synonyms

Tags: algorithm, database-design, data-structures, graph-databases, synonym

Hello all.
 I am new to this forum and also fresher in computer science industry so this question may seem unstructured. I am asking this question as I have to include it in my project. Even if you could not help me by exact answers I request you to show me path to reach to my answer.

**Question:** 
I am in process of finding self evolving data structure for alignment of **Terms** and **Phrases** (synonyms under some rules). For example `Mobile` and `Cell` will be synonyms if the query fired to find synonyms of mobile will also include some related parts (rules will be calling here).
 Neither meaning of Mobile and Cell can also be different.
 `Mobile` can also be `Mobile Library` ,`Mobile Hospital` etc. `Cell` can be biological term.

Work by Me

I have explored somewhat Nosql and Neo4j graph database. They are great but I was unable to find any useful concepts that can be relate to my question.

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how complex your rules need to be, but if it is as simple as your example, then you could use a simple relational model like so:

[image]

Your word list (`Term`) contains all of the words like "cell", "mobile" etc.  Your rule table (`Context`) lists the domain in which the terms are being used ("calling", "biology", etc.) and the linking table (`Synonym`) joins two `Terms` in one `Context`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joel. And ya the example (rule) mentioned here was quite simple. But what above user queries " I have been passing through cough , squeeze and fever in Florida" As these are causes for swine flu , What if at that time there are many patients passing through swine flu. So That this query should answer that " U may have swine Flu." What type of data structure can be here , I am giving example of medical domain bcz i have to include this in medical remedy engine.

Comment: @PawanParekh - I'm not clear on what it is you actually want to accomplish.  Relating a combination of symptoms to possible diagnoses is the subject for an expert system, not a synonym lookup table.  If this is what you're actually going for, then I suggest you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887533/how-do-20-questions-ai-algorithms-work

Comment: Sorry for so much late reply..I am using graph database to align them.