# how to add more complexity in my game?

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in functional programming I'm trying to make a game "Guess the country". This is the code I've written - how can I add more complexity? I need ideas - I want to give the player some points after he/she tells the right answer but I don't know how to add that.

```
game = do
         putStrLn "Welcome to the game"
         putStrLn "Press one to start"
         n1<- getLine
         let x1 = read n1::Int
         if(x1==1) then 
           putStrLn"DESCRIPTION: Write level 1 and  Guess the Country's name"
         else 
           putStrLn"exit"

    level 1= do
        putStrLn "It was discovered by columbus"
        ans1<- getLine
        if ans1=="america" then
          putStrLn "***CONGRATULATIONS***\n You've achieved 5 coins\n to move to next question write question2"
        else 
          putStrLn"Your answer is wrong\n***GAMEOVER***\nto try again write level 1"

    question2= do
        putStrLn "It is very famous for football"
        ans1<- getLine
        if ans1=="spain" then
          putStrLn "***CONGRATULATIONS***\n You've achieved 5 coins\n to move to next question write question3"
        else 
          putStrLn"Your answer is wrong\n***GAMEOVER***\nto try again write question2"

    question3 = do
         putStrLn "It is the largest country of the world"
         ans1<- getLine
         if ans1=="russia" then
           putStrLn "***CONGRATULATIONS***\n You've achieved 5 coins\n to move to next question write question4"
         else 
           putStrLn"Your answer is wrong\n***GAMEOVER***\nto try again write question3"
    question4 =do
        putStrLn "It has a maple leaf on its flag"
        ans1<- getLine
        if ans1=="canada" then
          putStrLn "***CONGRATULATIONS***\n You've achieved 5 coins\n to move to next question write question5"
        else 
          putStrLn"Your answer is wrong\n***GAMEOVER***\nto try again write question4"
    question5 = do
        putStrLn "It's capital is RIO DE JANEIRO"
        ans1<- getLine
        if ans1=="brazil" then
          putStrLn "***CONGRATULATIONS***\n You've achieved 5 coins\n to move to next level write level2"
        else 
          putStrLn"Your answer is wrong\n***GAMEOVER***\nto try again write question5"
    level2= do
         putStrLn"In this level you have to guess the countries capital \nwhats the capitol of china"
         ans1<- getLine
         if ans1=="bejing" then
            putStrLn "***CONGRATULATIONS***\n You've achieved 10 coins\n to move to next quest"`
```

Comment: Sorry, but there's no way this question could be objectively answered, which is a requirement on StackOverflow.

Comment: You could maybe ask for advice on the code you already _have_ on [Codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (there are quite a few things in it that aren't really idiomatic at all), and possibly in the discussion some ideas would also come up for how to proceed.

Comment: I'm a beginner, how am i supposed to learn if there is no answer?

Comment: Well, if you don't have ideas for what to do next then why not just read [books](https://wiki.haskell.org/Books#Textbooks) and look at their examples! But, surely you can come up with ideas of what could be _interesting_ for the program to do? That's not really bound to programming experience. (Judging how difficult the ideas are to implement might need experience, but that's something you could ask a question about.)

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little advanced, but the full [Twenty Questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Questions) game is described in the following two StackExchange Q&A's: [How do 20 questions AI algorithms work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887533/how-do-20-questions-ai-algorithms-work) and [How can I implement a “20 Questions” algorithm?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40024/how-can-i-implement-a-20-questions-algorithm) (has drawings + answer from author of [20Q.net](http://20q.net/)).

Perhaps you should ask yourself more concretely what kind of game you can make with only a small increment in complexity compared to your current game. Randomness makes games entertaining. Your current game has a fixed path.

For example, you could make a simple game where the end goal is to [guess a random number](https://wiki.haskell.org/Guess_a_random_number), with the program giving "higher / lower" hints. Someone already did this and submitted their code to the Code Review Stack Exchange: [Number Guessing Game in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134844/number-guessing-game-in-haskell), as @leftaroundabout suggested.

Since this problem already has pretty solutions online, you have to come up with a twist that you can only solve by yourself to be sure you're learning. A twist for the number guessing game could be an upper limit to how many guesses the player has.

---

A next step could be to make a random country guessing game where the hints to each country is still fixed, but the country is randomly chosen. Once you have made your mind about the flow of the program, you can define a datatype that models the content of your game. For example,

```
type Country = String
type Hint = String

countries :: [(Country, [Hint])]
countries = [ ("Denmark", [ "It is the smallest of Scandinavian countries."
                          , "It is the oldest kingdom in the world."
                          , ...
                          ]
            , ("Turkey", [ "It was established as a republic in 1923."
                         , "It is named after its founder, Kemal Atatürk."
                         ])
            , ...
            ]
```

This way, your program logic becomes independent of whatever particular questions you've got. This means you can make the game bigger by filling in *data* rather than complicating the logic of the game further.

You could *(a)* build a mechanism for picking a random country, and *(b)* build a mechanism for reading possible answers and determining if they're right, and *(c)* build a mechanism for giving more hints and count how many hints were needed, until you run out of hints.

Picking a random country you can learn how to do by doing the "guess a random number game". Picking a random country then becomes picking a random element from a list, which with the above `countries :: [(Country, [Hint])]` means picking a random element of the type `(Country, [Hint])`.

Reading possible answers and determining if they're right becomes a matter of comparing `answer <- getLine` with the value of type `Country` that you drew randomly.

And giving hints gets more complicated because you need to cycle the list of hints, give a new one when requested, and somehow disappoint the player when there are no more hints. Once you have a working game (for some definition of working), consider submitting this to the Code Review Stack Exchange. It's better to set the goals low and be done with some sub-game, than submit a bunch of code that isn't working, where the goal isn't clear, and your level of comprehension isn't at the level of your goal. This will only frustrate reviewers because a proper review may be wasted on you yet.